# Advanced counting

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

Someone is throwing a party with $n$ people in attendance( $n \ge 2$ including the host). Why are there at least two people at the party that have exactly same number of acquaintances present?

Comment: Let $k$ be the number of acquaintances of the $k^{\text{th}}$ guest. Then $k$ can only take $n-1$ values. Pigeonhole.....

Comment: @Anurag not quite. You can have 0 through $n-1$ acquaintances so pigeonhole doesn't apply. But you can do an induction proof based on it.

Comment: @MattSamuel assuming the acquaintance is symmetric and we are not counting self-acquaintance, then if there is a person with $n-1$ acquaintances, then how can there be a person with $0$ acquaintance? So either $k \in \{1,2,3, \ldots , n-1\}$ or $k \in \{0,1,2,3, \ldots , n-2\}$, either way it takes only $n-1$ values.

Comment: @Anurag that works too.